# Redirects been downgraded from Https to Http

Tags: spring, security, https, httpd.conf

We are facing an issue we don't really know where it's coming from.

Our application uses `Spring Cloud`, `Spring Oauth2` and `Spring Boot 1.5.9`. The entry point is an API-Gateway service using `Zuul` to redirect calls to the other microservices. There is an `Authorization-server` to handle the `Oauth2` authorization, not accessible from the outside but through the `API-Gateway`.

It is configured to use `Https` for every call that comes from clients and then we use `Http` once inside our system to communicate between microservices. It sits behind an `Apache proxy` configured with the certificates for using `Https` with port 80 disabled.

The problem we have at the moment is that every redirect from the `Spring Security` filters ends up being downgraded from `Https` to `Http` in the browser, which then fails as the port 80 is disabled and it cannot find the app.

The app used to work but now it doesn't. We use docker so we tried to redeploy the previous images but they don't work either. The `Apache conf` hasn't changed either.

We don't exactly know which part is failing, if it's the `Apache proxy` or the Spring config, specially when everything we can think of has been reverted to a previous working problem.

With this setup, what are the things that can force the redirect to change and how can we verify it? Could the `Spring Security` config affect this or is it more probably coming from the `Apache proxy`?

This is the `Apache config` we have at the moment:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/vpp-api/ssl/server-cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/vpp-api/ssl/server-key.pem

  SSLVerifyDepth 10
  SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/vpp-api/ssl/cacert.pem

  <location />
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/
  </location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the issue. Basically it was this line in the `Apache` conf:

```
ProxyPreserveHost on
```

It was changing the header `Location` as all requests redirected inside our system lose the `Https` protocol. All redirects sent back were using `Http` after this.

A solution to keep using this configuration is to manually override `Http` in the `Apache` conf with this:

```
Header edit Location ^http://(.*)$ https://$1
```