# Google chrome shows waiting for cache

Tags: php, google-chrome, ssl, https, browser-cache

I am using a bank payment gateway for my user payments in my website.

It is based on PHP and SOAP.

Recently, at the latest update of chrome(84.x) and in call back function, it  shows "waiting for cache" repeatedly in status bar.

There is no problem with FF and IE and previous versions of chrome.

If i remove browsing cache and cookies, it solves chrome problem for one payment. But the problem starts again for the second payment.

It is totally annoying problem.

Here is a simplified code:

```
function call() {
    ini_set ( "soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0" );
    
    
    $PIN = '1111';
    $wsdl_url = "https://URL/NewIPGServices/Sale/SaleService.asmx?WSDL";
    $site_call_back_url = "http://URL1/confirm.php";
    
    $amount = $_POST['Amount'] ? $_POST['Amount'] : "1000" ;
    $order_id = $_POST['OrderId'] ? $_POST['OrderId'] : "500";
    
    $params = array (
            "LoginAccount" => $PIN,
            "Amount" => $amount,
            "OrderId" => $order_id,
            "CallBackUrl" => $site_call_back_url 
    );
    
    $client = new SoapClient ( $wsdl_url );
    
    try {
        $result = $client->SalePaymentRequest ( array (
                "requestData" => $params 
        ) );
        if ($result->SalePaymentRequestResult->Token && $result->SalePaymentRequestResult->Status === 0) {
            header ( "Location: https://URL/NewIPG/?Token=" . $result->SalePaymentRequestResult->Token ); /* Redirect browser */
            exit ();
        }
        elseif ( $result->SalePaymentRequestResult->Status  != '0') {
            $err_msg = "(<strong> error : " . $result->SalePaymentRequestResult->Status . "</strong>) " .
             $result->SalePaymentRequestResult->Message ;
        } 
    } catch ( Exception $ex ) {
        $err_msg =  $ex->getMessage()  ;
    }
}

function callback() {

    $PIN = '1111';
    $wsdl_url = "https://URL/NewIPGServices/Confirm/ConfirmService.asmx?WSDL";
    
    $Token = $_REQUEST ["Token"];
    $status = $_REQUEST ["status"];
    $OrderId = $_REQUEST ["OrderId"];
    $TerminalNo = $_REQUEST ["TerminalNo"];
    $Amount = $_REQUEST ["Amount"];

    if ( $status == 0) {
        
        $params = array (
                "LoginAccount" => $PIN,
                "Token" => $Token 
        );
        
        $client = new SoapClient ( $wsdl_url );
        
        try {
            $result = $client->ConfirmPayment ( array (
                    "requestData" => $params 
            ) );
            if ($result->ConfirmPaymentResult->Status != '0') {
                $err_msg = "(<strong> error : " . $result->ConfirmPaymentResult->Status . "</strong>) " .
                 $result->ConfirmPaymentResult->Message ;
            }
        } catch ( Exception $ex ) {
            $err_msg =  $ex->getMessage()  ;
        }
    }elseif($status) {
        $err_msg = "status " . $status;
    }else {

        $err_msg = "no response " ; echo $err_msg;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: I noticed that after completing payment chrome goes to last `else` and shows "no response", but all other browsers successfully return.

**IMPORTANT EDIT**: It is because of transfer from '**https**' protocol from bank URL to '**http**' protocol of my website. It seems, it is a bug in new chrome update or they want to force websites to use SSL.
I have checked with bank a few minutes ago and there are many websites have this problem.
I don't know if there is a solution or we should wait for next chrome version or we have to use SSL

**EDIT**: I changed my site to https protocol but problem still exist with chrome!

Comment: Enter the developer console and disable cache.

Comment: @MarkusZeller, It goes to a loop showing "waiting for cache" in status bar. developer console shows anything.

Comment: @MarkusZeller, please read my post edit.

Comment: @MarkusZeller, please read my important edit.

Comment: Once coming from https you can not downgrade to http - as a security policy from Webkit. Just make `$site_call_back_url` also working with https and you should be good to go.

Comment: @MarkusZeller, is this a solution?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49072136/1906322

Comment: I can not tell, because https works only when the server has an appropriate signed certificate. You need to test that. You also could try to change just http to https. Alternatively you could try to [disable Chromes certficate verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388405/chrome-disable-ssl-checking-for-sites) (which is a very very bad idea).

Comment: @MarkusZeller... I changed my site to https, but problem still exists with chrome!!!

Comment: On Windows you need to use the certmgr and import your own signed certificate into the trusted root certificates. Then restart browser and it should work.

Comment: @MarkusZeller, windows and browsers have not any problem with certificate. I did not see any message about the certificate. Also i should mention, it is just a few hours i moved to https

Comment: Btw, opening that URL ends up in an endless reload.

Comment: @MarkusZeller ...open with Firefox or IE

Comment: @MarkusZeller , Yes you right it is Irrelevant... so it seems , it was not downgrade https to http.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the `waiting for cache` message from multiple sites, until they eventually time out.

As absurd as it is, the solution for me was to use safari until chrome randomly fixed itself.